# Write an infinite loop in Java

Tags: java, database

I have a situation where I need to run a Java code to determine certain database status (few specific counts only) in every 1s. I was planning to create an infinite loop which should only breaks out when the database is not running (stops administratively or accidentally). Could anyone show me a sample way to write the infinite loop which will not make any harm to the running database? Or, even if there is a better way to approach this objective to collect the data periodically?

Comment: Use a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: Use either a java.util.Timer or what @fge recommends.

Comment: I think you're trying to ask a good question but this needs improvement.  Show some code, show what you have tried and why it doesn't work or what you think might be wrong with it.

Comment: Some databases (notably PostgreSQL) allow to use NOTIFY/LISTEN mechanism, which allows to react to changes immediately and do not create tight loop, but use select loop instead

Answer (score 2):

Use `ScheduledExecutorService` service like following example:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
     Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

   public void beepForAnHour() {
     final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
       public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
     };

     final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);

     scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
       public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
     }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);

   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    BeeperControl bc=new BeeperControl();
    bc.beepForAnHour();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Ah, and don't forget to `@Override` the `run()` in `Runnable`

Comment: This is demo example. It beep after 10 second and after 1 hour the schedule will be cancelled. You should put your desired value.